# Stuck on Level 60 of Think Different

Tags: think-different

Hi could some one help me out on level 60 of think different. Here is the pic for your reference

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The answer is 36.
The top number times 4 equals the bottom left number, the number in center equals bottom right times 4.